# How do I remove tiles in a tilemap in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a tilemap(Tl) and when rocket hits it the tiles in a certain radius should destroy.

I have tried to get tiles using GetTilesBlock and Destroy function, but it just does not work

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        
            int posx = (int)transform.position.x;
            int posy = (int)transform.position.y;
            int posz = (int)transform.position.z;
            Vector3Int pos = new Vector3Int(posx, posy, posz);
            Vector3Int radiusBox = new Vector3Int(3, 3, 3);
            BoundsInt Box = new BoundsInt(pos, radiusBox);
            TileBase[] tiles = Tl.GetTilesBlock(Box);
            foreach(TileBase x in tiles)
            {
                Destroy(x);
            }
            

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: set the tiles[required pos] to null

Answer (score 0):

What I did was loop through all tiles within a box with sides of the radius and then check distance to make it a circle. If that sounds confusing then heres my code. A little messy but it gets the job done.

```cs
Vector2 pos = transform.position; //center of the circle

ground = FindAnyObjectByType<Tilemap>(); //Get the tilemap

for (int x = -ExplosionRadius; x ExplosionRadius; x++)
{
    for (int y = -ExplosionRadius; y < ExplosionRadius; y++) //find the box
    {
        Vector3Int Tilepos = ground.WorldToCell(new Vector2(pos.x + x, pos.y + y));
        if (Vector3.Distance(pos, Tilepos) <= ExplosionRadius) //check distance to make it a circle
        {
            ground.SetTile(Tilepos, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.